# A question about memory leaks

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

```
#include <QList>
class MyType{
//This has some data in it....
};

QList<MyType> f()
{
     QList<MyType> list;
     for(int i = 0; i<10; i++ )
     {
              MyType* item = new MyType();
              list << *item;
     }
     return list;
}

QList<MyType> temp_var = f();
```

When temp_var  goes out of the scope and destroys, what happens to the items that   we created and add to this list?
Is there going to be any memory leaks?

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear -- in your sample program, you are NOT storing the allocated objects in your `QList`, and neither are you storing pointers to your allocated objects. You are storing *copies* of your allocated objects. It seems like you meant to ask some other question? Did you mean to ask "What happens when a list of pointers is destoryed?"

Comment: @Rob: You are right, the question should have been "what happens when a list of pointers is destroyed?" and the obvious answer would have been "Memory leak".. but as you mentioned, I didn't know there's been "copy" objects in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there will be a memory leak. As a general rule, you must have one `delete` for each `new` in your program.

In your specific case, the faulty logic happens much earlier than `temp_var`'s destruction. You allocate the items, and then store a copy of those items in the list. You should immediately destroy the original, no-longer-useful items.

Your for loop could be :

```
 for(int i = 0; i<10; i++ )
 {
          MyType* item = new MyType(); // get me an item.
          list << *item;  // put copy of item in list
          delete item; // destroy my item
 }
```

When expressed that way, it is obvious that we shouldn't use `new` at all!

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    MyType item;
    list << item;
}
```

This version won't leak, assuming that `MyType` doesn't have any memory-management bugs of its own.

---

**EDIT**: As an aside, had your program been:

```
QList<MyType*> f() // List of POINTERS
{
     QList<MyType*> list;
     for(int i = 0; i<10; i++ )
     {
              MyType* item = new MyType();
              list << item;  // Storing a POINTER
     }
     return list;
}
```

Then, yes, you would have had precisely the memory leak you expected. `QList` does not automatically provide `delete` on pointer types.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any point of using `new` in your code, as you're not storing the pointers in the list, rather copies of the object created with new, and you're not deleteing it. So yeah, there is memory-leak in the function itself.

Seeing that `QList` is not a list of pointers, I can say that you shouldn't use `new` in your code:

```
QList<MyType> f()
{
     QList<MyType> list; //note : its not a list of MyType*
     for(int i = 0; i<10; i++ )
     {
              MyType item; //automatic variable
              list << item;
     }
     return list; 
}
```

Comment: This was just a sample, I just wanted to know what happens if we keep object from the heap in this situation, thanks for the answer though...

Comment: @Arsham: My answer addresses the problem with your sample (code). What else do you think I should talked about?

Comment: maybe my question didn't express it all. thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

When a QList gets destroyed / goes out of scope, it destroys its *content* with it. In your case, the content is made of **copies** of your objects (built from the implicit copy-constructor), not the objects themselves. The memory will leak in each iteration of the for-loop since the original object created by `new MyType()` will lose its pointer, but will remain allocated.

Comment: His code creates `QList<MyType>`, **not** `QList<MyType*>`. Doesn't that mean he is storing copies of the items, not pointers to them?

Comment: @Rob : My bad... I assumed by seeing the new MyType() that he was storing the pointer, editing my answer now...

Comment: @Rob: I agree. It was my bad too..Thanks for pointing that out. I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly will be a leak if it you don't delete all of those items you created with `new MyType()`!

In the destructor for `QList` you need to go through the list and call delete on each of those items.

Comment: He isn't storing the pointers in a QList, he is storing objects. `QList` will take care of destroying the items on the list.

Comment: @Arsham, I am beginning to think that I didn't understand the point of your question.

Comment: @Rob: it's funny that I got the answer I was looking for! thanks mate

Comment: @Arsham: I am beginning to think that *you* don't understand the point of your question.

Comment: @Rob You're right about the pointers not being stored, but the point remains that the `new` will cause a leak since the objects are never deleted.